# Select a hyperlink on webpage and store the content of resulting webpage in text file using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, automation, web-scraping, casperjs

I am trying to click on image link after the page loads completely.The image link is nested within the div tags as shown below

```
<section id="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="url" class="C">
                    <img src="http://www.example.com/xyz.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>                      
    </div>                                   
</section>
```

I am trying to load the image link and write its content to text file, but its not working with the code given below

```
var fs = require('fs');
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://www.example.com/');

var selector = "A > a:first-child";
casper.waitUntilVisible(selector)
    .thenClick(selector)
    .wait(10000)
    .waitTimeout = 90000 
    .then(function(){
        fs.write('myfile.txt', this.getHTML(), 'w');
    });

casper.run();
```

Comment: Your selector doesn't make any sense. I would expect `[data="E"] > a:first-child`. Also, what do you mean by *"its not working"*? What do you see and what do you expect to see?

Comment: I have edited my question and trying to avoid use of selector `[data="E"] > a:first-child` as the data value is dynamic on the different pages of websites and is not known to me.

Comment: Currently the output is nothing, casperjs doesn't show any error. I am expecting that the image hyperlink gets clicked and the source code of the resulting page gets stored in a text file. But, the code is not working. I am new to casperjs so i am confused about what is wrong with this code @artjomB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x > y` for a CSS selector means that the element matched by `y` is a child of an element matched by `x`. `A` as in `A > a:first-child` is not a valid selector based on your markup. I suspect that you want to use the `A` of the id which should be `#A > a:first-child`, but `a` is not a child of `#A`.

You either need to use the descendant operation (which is a space): `#A a:first-child` or fully qualify the selector: `#A > div.B > div > div > a:first-child`. Note that `:first-child` doesn't care which type the element is, so if `a` is not the first element it's parent, then this won't match anything. You could use `a:first-of-type`.

Additionally, this code will produce a TypeError, because `then` is not a function on a Number (`90000`). You cannot chain something when you set a property in this way. You would have to set the `waitTimeout` before starting or inside of a `then` function or callback.

Try:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://www.example.com/');

var selector = "#A > div > div > div > a:first-of-type";
casper.waitUntilVisible(selector)
    .thenClick(selector)
    .wait(10000)
    .then(function(){
        fs.write('myfile.txt', this.getHTML(), 'w');
    });

casper.run();
```

Comment: Why do we use four divs in selector value as the anchor tag is after the third div tag? @ArtjomB

Comment: I removed the `.waitTimeout` and added `casper.options.waitTimeout = 90000;` on the fourth line after `casper.start` line. I am facing timeout error specifying `wait timeout of 5000ms expired,exiting`. Can you please help me with this error @ArtjomB.

Comment: (1) This means that the very first `waitUntilVisible()` operation failed. Please check that you're on the correct page right after the start. (2) Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: PhatomJS version is 2.0.0.0

Comment: After registering for `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout`. `myfile.txt` file conists of source code of the main page(landing page on which image hyperlink is present) and not of the resulting page after click event as expected. The output of the image hyperlink is getting loaded inside the `section tag` and the page URL remains same. Is this causing the problem? @ArtjomB

Comment: (1) I don't know what's causing the problem. It seems to me from your last comment that you're not getting the timeout error anymore. What did you change beside adding those event handlers? (2) Try to run it with PhantomJS 1.9.8 and see if there are more errors. PhantomJS 2 has a bug that some errors are hidden. (3) Try to use a css selector without `:first-child` or `:first-of-type`, because PhantomJS has sometimes a bug with those.